# How to import transitions on demand from Element-UI

Tags: element-ui

I was wondering if there is a way to import the transitions from the Element-UI library on demand?

In their quick install section on there website ([here](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart)), they do explain how to import the components on demand, which works just fine, all you have to do is:

```
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';
import { Button } from 'element-ui';

Vue.use(Button)
```

And you're good to go. I don't know if it is possible with transitions though and I haven't been able to find an answer elsewhere.

Comment: There are instructions on the document - [component/transition](https://element.eleme.cn/#/en-US/component/transition), maybe you missed it when you checked it.

Comment: Oh jeez I'm blind. Thank you :-), that'll do.

Answer (score 0):

It's a built-in component, you will also need CSS. Check this `https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#css-based-transitions`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).